# From $\mathrm{GL}_{1}/K$ to $\mathrm{GL}_{2}/\mathbb{Q}$, where $K$ is a cyclic cubic extension

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, langlands-conjectures

(Migrated from MSE)

Let $K$ be a cyclic cubic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
For example, one can take [simplest cubic fields](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1974-28-128/S0025-5718-1974-0352049-8/S0025-5718-1974-0352049-8.pdf). By automorphic induction (which is known for cyclic extension of prime degree by Arthur-Clozel), any Hecke character $\chi$ on $K$ gives an automorphic representation $\Pi = \mathrm{AI}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{K}(\chi)$ on $\mathrm{GL}(3, \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. After doing some local computations myself, I *found* that $\pi$ is self-dual (I'm not 100% sure about this part - at least I think that there are many such $\chi$'s). Ramakrishnan proved that any self-dual $\mathrm{GL}(3)$ representations can be realized as adjoint of $\mathrm{GL}(2)$ representations up to quadratic characters, so that $\Pi = \mathrm{Ad}(\pi)\otimes \eta$ for some $\eta$ with $\eta^{2} = 1$. This process gives a way to construct $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ automorphic representation from $\mathrm{GL}(1, \mathbb{A}_{K})$ automorphic representation.

Here are my questions:

1. Is this valid? Aren't there any flaw in my argument?
2. If there isn't, can we specify the image of such *functoriality*? (I'm not sure if I could call this *functorial*) For example, what kind of modular forms (I think the Galois representation corresponds to $\pi$ might be odd, if exists) should correspond to the image of the process?

Comment: Could you explain why you think such a $\Pi$ has to be selfdual? This seems strange to me.

Comment: $\Pi$ is self-dual if and only if $L(s,\Pi)=L(s,\chi)$ has real Dirichlet coefficients. I don't think this is typical.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure $AI(\chi)$ is never self-dual unless $\chi$ is quadratic.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There was a mistake in my calculation. Could anyone give a proof that the condition holds when $\chi$ is quadratic?

Comment: If $\chi$ is quadratic, then $\chi$ itself is self-dual, and the dual of the induced representation is $Hom(C[G_{Q}]\otimes_{C[G_{K}]}\chi,C)=Hom_{C[G_{K}]}(C[G_{Q}],Hom(\chi,C))=Hom_{C[G_{K}]}(C[G_{Q}],\chi)$, which is again isomorphic to the induced representation as the coinduction and the induction agree for representations of finite groups.